# Bootstrap 4 - text refuses to go in the middle of a div

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Hey everyone I have this piece of code:

```
    <div class="row mt-5" id="System Requirments">
        <div class="col-4">
            <h4 class="text-nowrap font-weight-bold pl-4">System Requirments</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-light rounded" style="width:500px;">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-minimal-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-minimal" aria-controls="pills-minimal" aria-selected="true">
                        Minimal
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="pills-recommended-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-recommended" aria-controls="pills-recommended" aria-selected="false">
                        Recommended
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content ml-4 mt-3">
                <!-- Minimal -->
                <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-minimal" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-minimal-tab">
                    <div class="row">
                        <p class="text-left">Processor:</p>
                        <p class="text-center font-weight-bold">@Model.MinRequirments.Processor</p>
                    </div>
```

(there is of course more context for this but I'm unsure if it's needed, don't be afraid to ask for it!)
the problem is with the last 4 lines, the `MinRequirments.Processor` doesn't go in the middle (the @ sign is Blazor syntax) I tried alot of classes but I'm unsure why it doesn't work, this is how it looks now:
[image]

I want the bolded text to be in the middle, can anyone help me? (added red background for clarity)

EDIT: removed the rows since they were not needed, now I have this piece of code

```
                <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-minimal" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-minimal-tab">
                    <p class="text-left">Processor:</p>
                    <p class="font-weight-bold text-center">@Model.MinRequirments.Processor</p>
```

which generated this:[image]
How can I remove the line between the 2 paragraphs but keep the text in the middle?

Comment: Horizontal or vertical? In the middle of the entire tab, or relative to Processor?

Comment: I want the "Intel Proc." to go to the right, right in the middle of the 2 buttons, that's how I mean center,I just don't understand why ``text-center`` doesn't work here

Comment: You forgot to add a column inside a row. `<p>` tags should be inside that column.

Comment: The Bootstrap `row` should *only* be used as a container of columns (`col`)

Comment: Now there is a line between the 2 paragraphs that doesn't look too good and i can't inline it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my question by using cols correctly:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
        <p class="text-left">Processor:</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <p class="text-left font-weight-bold">@Model.MinRequirments.Processor</p>
    </div>
</div>
```